# How to only display certain combinations in a table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I've got a table that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9isFJ.png). The table is a set of combinations and for every Agent/Client/Month combination, there is a column "Match?". The column "Match?" basically describes whether a client and an agent match in the given month. I was wondering whether there is a way to only display combinations, where "Match?" is "yes". I was thinking that maybe I could exclude combinations with "Match? = 0" in the index view? Any ideas?

Comment: you can use where  .. match='Yes' ..

Comment: in the index view?

Comment: you have mysql  .. you can filter in the query  result ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Syntax:**

```
TableName.where(fieldName: value)
```

For you,

```
TableName.where(match: 'yes')
```

**You can take the above line in either controller, or indexview.**

But, I prefer taking it in controller in a variable and use that in view,

Eg:

**Incontroller,**

```
@matched_data  = TableName.where(match: 'yes').first
```

**In View:**

```
<%= @matched_data %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Then just use a `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE match = 'YES'
```